# Windows phone 8: where and how to access files?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, file-io

I have built a quizz app in C#/xaml that works fine on my computer and would like to port it on windows phone 8.
Here is how it works : I have a two columns .txt file : first column is a country, 2nd is the capital city. The program randomly selects a country and proposes 4 possible answer the user has to choose from.
I managed to port the game on my phone but I can't find how to use my .txt file.

To read the file I've written this method :

```
static List<Countries> openFile(string fileName)
    {
        string line = null;
        List<string> liste = new List<string>();
        List<Countries> countries = new List<Countries>();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName)) //fileName = "capitals.txt")
        {
            line = reader.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                liste.Add(line);
                line = reader.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        foreach (string ttt in countries)
        {
            string[] test = ttt.Split('\t');
            countries.Add(new Countries() { nomPays = test[0], Capitale = test[1] });
        }
        return countries;
    }
```

My problem is very dumb. I don't know where to put the file on my computer to debug the program, visual studio keeps indicating it can't locate the file. 
In the IDE, I tries to find where he is looking the file for. I found it was supposed to be located in a folder somewhere in "appdata\packages\" but when I look for that folder, it does not exist (I have checked that hidden files and folders are displayed).

One thing I tried, was to add the file manually in the assets, but I still can't open it. Maybe am I using the wrong method to open the file ? I've tried different options to open the file, such as :

```
//get local folder
StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var dataFolder = await local.GetFolderAsync("dataFolder");
var file = await local.OpenStreamForReadAsync("Capitals.txt");
```

Or :

```
var uri = new System.Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Capitals.txt");
var file = Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync
```

But neither work, I keep having a file not found error.

My question is simple : 1/ Where should I put my file on my hard drive while working on the software and 2/ How should I access this file ?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Did you try to put your file in local folder of your app? You can find full path in your code here: StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried your suggestion :StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder; Then used a label to print the path : label.Text = local.Path. The label indicates a path but I can't find it on my computer .. Is this because I've launched the app choosing "device" rather than "emulator" ? Does visual studio delete the path when the app is terminated ?

Comment: 1. You can see this value just by placing breakpoint in code and see it in the variable. 2. If you are deploying your app to the   device this local folder will be created on the device. 3. This folder is saved on device until application will be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally figured out how to locate the file using your tip. I also created directly the file on my computer by adding it from VS IDE (right click on Assets folder). Now my problem is I can't read the file properly using the method Streamreader as before ...